# How do I turn this JavaScript into a footnote using Bootstrap and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-grid

My teacher wants us to display this date as a footnote with Bootstrap and I’m not quite sure how to do that.

```
const last = moment(document.lastModified, "MM/DD/YYYY");
const now = moment();

document.write('The last modified date is: ' + last.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + ' and the current date is: ' + now.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Why are you using `document.write` instead of standard DOM APIs or jQuery?

Comment: Use like this
var str = 'The last modified date is: ' + last.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + ' and the current date is: ' + now.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
document.getElementById("footnote").innerHTML(str);

Comment: this might help : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_sup.asp